# copy botton in slider revolotion v6.6.18

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider, slider-revolution

I have a button that I want to copy a text when the user clicks on it.
I use Slider Revolution version 6.6.18

I made a button and called the javascript code in the function field, but nothing happens

there is any solutions for this problem

i'll glad if you help me in this